# Regular Expression - Match any character except +, empty string should also be matched

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a bit of trouble with one part of a regular expression that will be used in JavaScript.  I need a way to match any character other than the `+` character, an empty string should also match.

`[^+]` is almost what I want except it does not match an empty string.  I have tried `[^+]*` thinking: "any character other than `+`, zero or more times", but this matches everything including `+`.

Comment: How is it possible that `[^+]*` matches a `+`? That doesn't make sense. There must be something else wrong with your expression.

Comment: @ScottRippey: I guessed (in my answer) that the `*` quantifier was allowing the match to succeed by matching nothing (zero characters that are not a `+`) successfully. With no anchors or other assertions, it could theoretically match either before or after the `+`, thus allowing the entire string to match. (of course it would match before because that's the first one, and it would stop there) does this assessment not make sense to you?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Add a {0,1} to it so that it will only match zero or one times, no more no less:

```
[^+]{0,1}
```

Or, as FailedDev pointed out, `?` works too:

```
[^+]?
```

As expected, testing with Chrome's JavaScript console shows no match for `"+"` but does match other characters:

```
x = "+"
y = "A"

x.match(/[^+]{0,1}/)
[""]

y.match(/[^+]{0,1}/)
["A"]

x.match(/[^+]?/)
[""]

y.match(/[^+]?/)
["A"]
```

Comment: No you don't need to escape it, secondly {0,1} = ?. +1 Nevertheless.

Comment: Both options seem to match everything, including just + according to http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: According to the site above, that one doesn't match anything.

Comment: @zaq I have never used that regex tester, so I cannot say if it actually works or not, but when you try it in *your* application does it work?  Also, try it out in chrome's javascript console.

Comment: @zaq: It looks like that site lets you test to see if a regex matches *any part* of a given string. So, to use that site to test if `[^+]*` matches an *entire* string, you'll want to put it in the form `^([^+]*)$`.

Comment: @zaq - Actually, just tested `^([^+]{0,1})$` and it works on that site (matches all single characters except `+` and matches empty string).  Although you do need to remove the ^$ around it before using it in a larger regex.  That site does its matches weird, it seems to be non-greedy by default when the default should be greedy.  @ruakh He just wants to match a single character.

Comment: That seems to be it.  It is necessary to bound it with ^$.  Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

- `[^+]` means "match any single character that is not a `+`"
- `[^+]*` means "match any number of characters that are not a `+`" - which almost seems like what I think you want, except that it will match zero characters if the first character (or even all of the characters) are `+`.

use anchors to make sure that the expression validates the ENTIRE STRING:

```
^[^+]*$
```

means:

```
^       # assert at the beginning of the string
[^+]*   # any character that is not '+', zero or more times
$       # assert at the end of the string
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're just testing the string to see if it doesn't contain a `+`, then you should use:

```
^[^+]*$
```

This will match only if the ENTIRE string has no `+`.

Comment: This is actually just part of a larger expression so I don't necessarily want to match the entire string.